# Is there a clean way to use Groovy's extension methods in Kotlin?

Tags: groovy, extension-methods, kotlin, jvm-languages

For example, Groovy allows to get text of a file represented by `java.nio.file.Path` as follows:

```
// Groovy code
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

Path p = Paths.get("data.txt")
String text = p.text
```

I would like to be able to reuse Groovy's `text` extension method in Kotlin.

**Please note**: I know [Kotlin has a related method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) for this particular case. Still, there might be Groovy methods which are useful for Kotlin users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to write a simple wrapper [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) in Kotlin:

```scala
// Kotlin code
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods

fun Path.text(): String {
  return NioGroovyMethods.getText(this)
}
```

Which then can be used like:

```scala
// Kotlin code
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

fun usageExample() {
  val p: Path = Paths.get("data.txt")
  val text: String = p.text()
}
```

If using Gradle to build the project, this means Groovy has to be added to dependencies:

```
// in build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
}
```